# Can I run emacs as server on Linux but attach from Windows?

Tags: linux, emacs, windows

I am able to run emacs as server daemon and attach back to it on Linux.

Is it possible to start emacs as daemon on Linux, but attach back to it from Windows with a different client?

Emacs or xemacs, both are okay.

to be precise, I want to start a emacsclient windows client to connect to linux emacs server. so putty or exceed or screen is not precisely what I want to do.

is it possible.

Comment: This question has been reposted on http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15144/emacsclient-to-access-remote-emacs-server . It has better/newer answers there.Perhaps consider deleting this one?

Comment: It's not cross-posting if it's done by different users (especially if they're years apart).  While identifying (and linking to) the similar question is useful, I don't see any reason to close this question, let alone delete it.  (After all, if people search U&L for this question, we want that they should find *something*.)

Answer (score 2):

Start emacs within screen and (re-)connect via ssh (putty) and screen -x?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Verbatim from the emacs wiki:
*Running emacs like a Daemon

This a new feature that is included in emacs-23.1.*

**Simple setup**

*Put*

```
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
```

*in your .bashrc, or*

```
setenv ALTERNATE_EDITOR ""
```

*in your .cshrc depending on your default shell.*

*After that using `emacsclient` (or `emacsclient -t`) will automatically start an Emacs in daemon mode and connect to it if one is not found running.*

It has been thoroughly documented with specific instructions for numerous linux distributions in an easy to follow and understand way on the wiki, which is also the authoritative resource: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon